# How to load js file from another js file in angular 2 - webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to re-use some functionallity that we have built using three.js and that we are successfully using on our second project which is built on PHP.

Now I want to import the same thing to Angular 2 project that is using webpack.

Currently I'm struggling with one issue. In the JS file we have piece of code:

```
loader.load( base_url + 'tmp/' + 'model.js', function( object ){
            console.log("File loaded successfully");
    }
```

that was copied from our second website. That code needs to load file from  base url, tmp folder and file is called model.js

I put that file in angular 2 project at root where I created tmp/ folder and I added model.js into that folder.

But, `console.log("File loaded successfully");` was never executed.

I tried to use Chrome console to debug what is wrong.

When I put breakpoint on loader.load and type in a console full path to the file

```
loader.load("http://localhost:4200/tmp/model.js", function(object) { 
console.log("test");
});
```

I'm getting message 
"undefined".

Of course I was not able to get my file trough web browser typing in url

```
http://localhost:4200/tmp/model.js
```

because everything was pre-packed and moved into main.bundle.js file.

Is there any workaround ? Any suggestion and advice will be helpful.

Comment: why don't you just `require` instead of `loader.load`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27509/573032

Comment: What is the exact issue here. model.js is available with bundle. then what is your problem??

Comment: Issue was because I created tmp/ folder in a root of the project. I move the tmp/ folder with model.js to src/ where is my application and it started to load file as expected using loader.load(...).. @JaganathanBantheswaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put tmp/ folder at the root, instead in src/ folder where is my application.

Where are main.ts that bootstrap whole app and all other files / folders.

I moved simply from root to src/ folder and it started to work.

I was also able to access to that js files trough the browser via url:
http://localhost:4200/tmp/model.js